# Call Activity.setResult() from activity which is already finished

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, onactivityresult

I am trying to implement deep linking in my android app.

My use case is when a user clicks on deep linking url and then selects my app for payment then my application's `ActivityA` gets opened (launcher activity) and then after finishing `ActivityA`, from there my `ActivityB` gets opened and from there, after finishing `ActivityB`, `ActivityC` gets opened. Now in `ActivityC` after making the payment I want to call `setResult()` method in order to send payment data back to the previous app.

My question is as `ActivityA` is already finished how can I call `setResult()` in order to send response back?

Also I am finishing `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` because when user presses back button I don't want my user to go back to these activities.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: your question is ambiguous pleas clarify

Comment: sorry but what you are not getting can you all please tell me ?? also thanks for helping me out of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT) is the intent flag you need to apply when you are navigating between `ActivityA` to `ActivityB` and then to `ActivityC`. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT):

> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity. This way the new activity can call **setResult(int)** and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` because i tried to use all 3 of them together but the flags weren't working correctly.

Comment: are you there ??

Comment: Can you please look at m new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096603/in-android-use-intent-forward-result-with-new-task-and-clear-task.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware about usages in conjuction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.